# Is there any situation where this C code would not work as intended?

Tags: c, type-conversion, memcpy

Is there any possible situation on an x86 or x64 computer where this program would not output 0xFFFF?  Or is it guaranteed to work without issues?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned short int s = 0;
    unsigned long int l = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    memcpy(&s, &l, sizeof(short));
    printf("0x%.4X", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should that be `printf("0x%.4hX", s);` instead, to stop printf interpreting its argument as a (plain) int?

Comment: `memset(&s, 0xFF, sizeof(short))` should produce `FFFF` on all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C does not guarantee the maximum size of a data type, only the minimum one, if you use a compiler with `unsigned long` taking more than 32 bits where the address of the initial byte corresponds to the most-significant byte of the `unsigned long` (i.e. the big endian) this would not produce the `FFFF` result.

Comment: Do you mean the least-significant byte?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I described big endian, but wrote little endian.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, because the `.4` specifier for `printf` specifies a minimum, not a maximum. If `short int` has 32 bits instead of 16 (which is permitted, as it only has a minimum size according to the standard) "0xFFFFFFFF" would be printed instead.

Otherwise, given that x86 and x64 are little-endian, this will usually happen, because the "FF" bytes are stored at the beginning of the long int. The long int has bit pattern "FF FF FF FF", and the short int is being taken from the beginning.

Even if a long int is 64 bits the "FF" bytes will still be at the beginning: "FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00".

Even the following outputs "0xFFFF", where we have less FF bytes in the long int:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned short int s = 0;
    unsigned long int l = 0xFFFF;
    memcpy(&s, &l, sizeof(short));
    printf("0x%.4X", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good point that short could be more than 16 bits, though i have never seen that in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes it's guaranteed, given x86/x64 is little-endian

Comment: Endianness is determined by the C implementation, not the hardware. The question asks if there is **any possible situation** where the program would not output “0xFFFF”. There is: We can write a big-endian C implementation even on little-endian hardware.